# return only paragraph by filtering command ouput

Tags: bash, shell, filter, awk, grep

Is there a way to return only second or third, fourth paragraph using `grep`, `awk`...?

How can I get the `lo` paragraph, I know that's possible using command `ifconfig lo` but how if use other commands. The output from `ifconfig` is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:22:b2:8b:0d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.22  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:22ff:feb2:8b0d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:100979 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:129240044 (129.2 MB)  TX bytes:7355272 (7.3 MB)
          Interrupt:29 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily filter by either paragraph number or interface name using `awk`.

For paragraph number just specify which record with `awk 'NR==1' RS=''`:

```
# First record
$ ifconfig | awk 'NR==1' RS=''
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:22:b2:8b:0d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.22  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:22ff:feb2:8b0d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:100979 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:129240044 (129.2 MB)  TX bytes:7355272 (7.3 MB)
          Interrupt:29 

# Second Record              
$ ifconfig | awk 'NR==2' RS=''
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

If you want to filter by interface name and not record number then `awk '$1=="eth0"' RS=''`:

```
# Interface lo
$ ifconfig | awk '$1=="lo"' RS='' 
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

# Interface eth0                                                        
$ ifconfig | awk '$1=="eth0"' RS='' 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:22:b2:8b:0d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.22  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:22ff:feb2:8b0d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:100979 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:129240044 (129.2 MB)  TX bytes:7355272 (7.3 MB)
          Interrupt:29
```

But I don't know what is wrong with `ifconfig eth0` or `ifconfig lo`.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
BEGIN {
  RS = ""
}

NR == 3 {
  print
  exit
}
```

That prints the third paragraph.  Change the "3" to whatever you like.  Note that setting the Record Separator to the empty string makes awk work on paragraphs rather than lines as usual.

You can run it like this:

```
awk -f above.awk input.txt
```

Comment: You can change `NR == 3` to `/^lo[ \t]+/` (I can't use `\s` in awk?) to print the paragraph starting with `"lo "`.

Comment: \s is a shorthand SOME tools implement for the the POSIX character class [[:space:]] - always use [[:space:]] and you won't get surprises.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the "+" since 1-or-more includes 1 so if you have `lo` followed by a space, it matches either RE. In this case `$1=="lo"` is probably clearer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [pattern range](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29), here's one way using `sed`. It will also remove the last empty line:

```
ifconfig | sed -n '/^lo/,/^$/ { /^$/!p }'
```

The `awk` solution:

```
ifconfig | awk '$1=="lo"' RS=
```